# How to find integral curves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given a pair of differential equations and I am supposed to find the integral curves that satisfy initial conditions, how do I go about this?

$$dx/dt = -x(1-y)$$  with $t_0 = 0, \quad x(t_0) = 0.5$

$$dy/dt = y(1-x)$$ with $t_0 = 0, \quad y(t_0) = 2$

Comment: As a hint, can you use $\dfrac{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}}{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}} = \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$?

Comment: from there, do I separate and integrate?

Comment: Yeah, and of course, you have $x$ and $y$ at $t_0$ as your condition.

Comment: This is a special case of the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey system, often used as example/test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the initial conditions are $x(0)=0.5,y(0) = 2$. To find the integral curves one have to eliminate the parameter in equations and then integrate. As [@KM101](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/596598/km101) stated above, we can write

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{y(1-x)}{-x(1-y)}\Rightarrow \frac{(y-1)}{y}dy=\frac{1-x}{x}dx\Rightarrow y-\ln y=\ln x -x+c$$

by substituting initial conditions we get

$$2-\ln(2)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}+c\Rightarrow c=\frac{5}{2}$$

The explicit formula of $y$ as a function of $x$ is not possible to obtain (well it is possible to obtain a closed form expression of $y$ as a function of $x$ but it involves the Lamber-W function which is not an elementary mathematical function).

Comment: thanks! You have both been a massive help!